# Any FOSS MATLAB/Octave toolbox for high-speed variable precision arithmetic?

Tags: matlab, software, floating-point, precision, symbolic-computation

I need to use variable precision arithmetic in MATLAB for an expensive set of computation.

The vpa function provided by the symbolic math toolbox is very slow. I found a non-free alternative toolbox known as "Advanpix" (http://www.advanpix.com/) ,which sped up things by an order of magnitude, using a trial version.

However, my funding body does not allow purchase of any additional software for this project.

Is there a viable/fast alternative to advanpix/vpa for MATLAB ?

Comment: What about [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6446-multiple-precision-toolbox-for-matlab)?

Comment: Still quite slow compared to advanpix. Also, seems to be relatively old package. Is there any other toolbox ?

Comment: Have you tried [mpmath]( http://mpmath.org/) on Python?

Comment: Do you need full variable precision or just extended precision, e.g., quad precision?

Comment: Quad precision works just fine. Is there a quad precision option in MATLAB? yes, I am aware of mpmath for python. But unfortuantely, my simulation code is quite complex (about 3000 lines of code) and I don't want to move to python currently.

Comment: Sometimes if you want the best stuff, you have to pay up.  BTW, I'd like to have the nicest house in the world - and i need to get it for free.

Answer (score 3):

While I do not know of a toolbox which fits the bill, a good open source alternative to MATLAB and Octave which does have a good solution to this problem is Julia. The linear algebra syntax from MATLAB/Octave almost transfers over to Julia directly, though you need to swap indexing like `A(i)` to `A[i]`. But after a quick translation, you can use Julia's `BigFloats` for variable precision numbers. That's a wrapper of the MPFR library which is pretty standard and does okay. A faster implementation for bitsizes <500 is given in ArbFloats.jl which is based on the Arb library. Lastly, if you just want 128-bit numbers, DecFP.jl gives some good implementations.

What's nice about going this route is that Julia's dispatch system makes these just stand-in for standard numbers, so you can use them in most well written libraries. So you can take these high-speed variable precision numbers and just call generic matrix multiplication, SVD factorization, `\`, differential equation solvers, optimization routines, etc. and expect them to work in place of `Float64`s.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, there are other inseparable pieces of this complex project (about 3000 lines of code) which relies on external MATLAB-only toolboxes, and hence migrating to Julia at this stage looks difficult. However, I had a look at the julia library and it seems to be useful for future projects. Thanks a lot for the suggestion though.